# Dictionary in Dictionary value search

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am downloading information from a Firebase database and it is being inputted via a for loop into:

```
static var Reports = [String:[String:String]]()
```

I need to figure out a way to search the inside values for a certain string

I have messed around with this but can't seem to get it inside the inside dictionary (If that makes sense)

```
for values in Reports.count {
    if let item = Reports["favorite drink"] {
        print(item)
    }
}
```

I need to have a search string then a number of times the value appears like so:

```
func findString(dict Dictionary) -> Int {
     var ReportsLevel1 = 0
          (for loop I'm guessing)
          search here for string
     return ReportsLevel1
}
```

Tip: the outside dictionary keys are not set in stone, they depend on what time and date the report was submitted

Comment: Some tips to get you started, you can get all keys from a dictionary with .keys and all values with .values so Reports.values would give you access to the inner dictionary.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Correct, but to get the values of the inner array I would need something similar to Reports.values.values correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out the `numberOfTimes` in which `"yourSearchString"` appears you can do as follows

```
var numberOfTimes = 0
for internalDictionary in reports.values
{
    for value in internalDictionary.values
    {
        if (value == "yourSearchString") { numberOfTimes += 1 }
    }
}
```

or

```
let numberOfTimes = reports.flatMap { internalDictsArray in internalDictsArray.value.filter { $0.value == "yourSearchString" } }.count
```